# How to allow angle "<>" brackets when including a Bazel header?

Tags: c++, bazel, abseil

My project is transitioning to [Bazel](https://bazel.build) from [CMake](https://cmake.org) and I am including a snapshot of [Abseil](https://abseil.io) by checking it into a `third_party/` top-level directory within our repository. I need to support both build systems during the transition, so I created `CMakeLists.txt` files and noticed that quite a lot of warnings need to be disabled for the Abseil headers to compile.

For CMake, this okay because I can include the headers where I use them by using the `#include <absl/strings/str_cat.h>` syntax. This tells my compiler that it's a system header and to ignore the warnings so I don't have to disable them globally.

For Bazel, though, I get this error:

> error: 'absl/strings/str_cat.h' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead

Is there a way to tell Bazel to allow the `<>`-style includes? Is there another way to disable warnings just for these headers without also disabling them for the whole project?

Comment: Can't you add the include directory in Bazel? It talks about certain flags to add here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-and-cpp.html#include-paths.

Comment: Could you add a symbolic link in the system include path to point to your needed directory? Perhaps Bazel will see this as the same as <iostream>.

Comment: Could you share what those warnings are?  Abseil has a goal of being warning free, even for Visual Studio.  (Google internally has a lot of warnings enabled, with warnings-as-errors turned on, so we're sympathetic to wanting those compiler warnings not to be triggered.)

Answer (score 0):

By default Bazel doesn't emit any cc-library-specific include (`-I`) directory flags for compile actions. Since include lookup is not free we rely on a single rooted header hierarchy. But you can tell Bazel to add custom include directories by using [`includes`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.includes) on a given `cc_library`. Or, preferably, use [`strip_include_prefix`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.strip_include_prefix) and [`include_prefix`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.include_prefix).